# JSHint with Browserify bundles

Tags: browserify, jshint, lint

I'm using browserify and watchify to bundle up my script files [in line with this recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md). However, when I add JSHint to the mix where it says to `// Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.` the reporter throws errors and warnings on the bundle.js file.

Based on that recipe how can I add JSHint to check my JS files before bundling?

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: Gulp. Exactly in line with the linked recipe.